# Select elements filtering them if they belong to nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I want to select elements that have class target. This is what I am using to  do so,
`$(.container).find('.target);`
But, the problem is it targets the elements that are children of nested container. So, how do I filter the selection, so as to target only the elements belonging to current container element. For example, for the parent 'container' element, I need to select elements that have class 'target' and text is 'select this via jquery' (note: actual elements to be selected can have any content inside them).

The HTML markup is like this:

```
<div id="my-container-1" class="container" data-name="container-1">
<div class="inside-wrapper">
    <div class="inside">
        <div id="my-container-1-container-2-0" class="container" data-name="container-1:container-2">
            <div class="inside-wrapper">
                <div class="inside"></div>
                <div class="target">select this for container(my-container-1-container-2-0)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="target">select this for container(my-container-1)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
        <div id="my-container-1-container-2-1" class="container" data-name="container-1:container-2">
            <div class="inside-wrapper">
                <div class="inside">
                    <div class="target">select this for container(my-container-1-container-2-1)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="maybe-other-wrapper-class">
            <div class="target">select this for container(my-container-1)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
        <div id="my-container-1-container-2-2" class="container" data-name="container-1:container-2">
            <div class="inside-wrapper">
                <div class="inside"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="target">select this for container(my-container-1)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="target">select this for container(my-container-1)</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**: This is my current solution ([jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/1ubuvhtk/5/)) which seems to be working, but not sure if this is the best way to do it.

```
var module = (function ($) {
var module = {};
//@todo This should return target elements that belong 
//to the passed container element and not parent or child container
module.getTarget = function (container) {
    return container.find('.target').filter(function () {
        return $(this).closest('.container').data('name') === container.data('name');
    });
};

$(function () {
    $('.container').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        console.log(module.getTarget($(this)));

    });
});

return module;
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what do you mean by current container element ? There are lots of container... which container you're talking about?

Comment: If you can tell your current container on the basis of some event which gives some element then you can do $(element).closest('.container').find('.target');

Comment: I have updated the example html markup to closely resemble my actual implementation, hope it explains things better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude nested `.target`.

```
$('.container .target:not(.container .container .target)')
```

Check out this example - http://jsbin.com/babiviziye/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Since, I can have a container inside container any level deep, it doesn't work for nested container. I have updated my question, hopefully it does explain things better.